# Github Action fails on Laravel project

Tags: laravel, github-actions, service-provider

That's my .yaml file

```
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
      branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
      branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:

  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
    with:
      php-version: '8.1'
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Copy .env
    run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
  - name: Install Dependencies
    run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
- name: Generate key
  run: php artisan key:generate
- name: Directory Permissions
  run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
- name: Create Database
  run: |
    mkdir -p database
    touch database/database.sqlite
- name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
  env:
    DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
    DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
  run: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

And I'm also using **GenreServiceProvide**

```
$allGenres = Genre::where('isActive', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();
View::share([
    'allGenres' => $allGenres,
]);
```

**Run php artisan key:generate**

That's error

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `genres` where `isActive` = 1 and `genres`.`deleted_at` is null order by `name` asc)
```

How can I fix that ?

> There is no problem if I comment all the codes in this file in my project, but I want it to work in github action as well

Comment: Can you please say at which step do you have this error? Is this error happens on artisan commands or test commands?

Comment: on artisan commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error before, and if you think about it you can already guess that you don't need `$allGenres` variable because you are in CI/CD and therefor you don't have any view to share it with.

So i always tend to disable these kind of queries on providers for CI/CD, mostly by checking if i'm in console or not. But sometimes if i need this in console commands the trick i use is i add an env variable just for CI/CD (in github action) and then in provider i check if i'm in CI/CD then i don't query. The code will be something like this:

```php
if (! app()->runningInConsole()) {
    $allGenres = Genre::where('isActive', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();
    View::share([
        'allGenres' => $allGenres,
    ]);
}
```

Or if i have set the env variable then i use something like this

```php
if (! env('IS_CI_ENV', false)) {
    $allGenres = Genre::where('isActive', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();
    View::share([
        'allGenres' => $allGenres,
    ]);
}
```

For action:

```yaml
...
jobs:
  laravel-tests:

  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  env:
    IS_CI_ENV: true

...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your workflow file, you've specified DB_CONNECTION: sqlite for the testing environment, but it seems like the application is still trying to use a MySQL connection.

To fix this issue make sure that your Laravel application is configured to use the SQLite connection when running in the GitHub Actions environment. You can set this in your .env or via the GitHub Actions workflow.

That's the modified version of your `.yaml` file:

```
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
      branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
      branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Set up PHP
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: '8.1'
    
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest

    - name: Set up application for SQLite
      run: |
        touch database/database.sqlite
        echo "DB_CONNECTION=sqlite" >> .env
        echo "DB_DATABASE=${{ github.workspace }}/database/database.sqlite" >> .env

    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: It returns this error after changing the .yaml file

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: NO) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `genres` where `isActive` = 1 and `genres`.`deleted_at` is null order by `name` asc)